# Poisson distribution and hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

The number of accidents in a year in a city is $X \sim Po(\lambda)$. Last year there were $N < \lambda$ accidents in the city. Is it true that the accident rate has increased? Study this question for $\lambda = 15$ and $N = 10$.

I think that the hypothesis testing is
$$
H_0 : \lambda \leq 15, \quad H_1 : \lambda > 15.
$$
Then for acceptance region
$$
0.05 = \alpha = P(X > k | \lambda = 15) = 1 - P(X \leq k | \lambda = 15).
$$
I want to compute $P(X \leq k)$ when $\lambda = 15$ but the expression is a Taylor expansion and I cant obtain $k$ with this equation. Is it correct the previous argue?

Comment: If $N \lt \lambda$ then this might be evidence suggesting the accident rate has reduced but I would have thought it is not going to be evidence that the rate has increased

Comment: Using R, `qpois(1-0.05, lambda=15)` suggests $k=22$ might be what you are looking for

Comment: Since $k = 22$ then the acceptance region should be $[0,22]$? It looks strange because if $N = 20$, i.e, $N > 15$ then we accept $H_0$, i.e., the accident rate dropped...

Comment: Traditionally you do not "accept the null hypothesis" but instead "fail to reject the null hypothesis"